# Could the US fed gov reduce a state's minimum wage?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, federalism

I am aware the Fed can create a minimum wage law that is more restrictive than a state's, but could it nullify a state's minimum wage law and force it to be lowered?

Comment: Do you have in mind any particular legal theory that might allow the federal government to impose a ceiling on the level of state minimum wage?

Comment: @phoog It would be a simple case of [preemption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_preemption). Federal law sets a minimum minimum wage, it could just as easily set a uniform minimum wage. Similarly, [half of the states](https://blog.petrieflom.law.harvard.edu/2019/01/30/preemption-state-minimum-wage-laws-and-a-public-health-lens/) have preempted local minimum wage laws.

Comment: @user71659 states have a significantly different relationship to their subdivisions than does the US to the states. Municipalities exist because the state law says they exist, and the state has essentially total control over municipal ordinances.  States can limit municipal minimum wages just so. Federal preemption of state law works differently.  First, the federal law needs a basis in the US constitution, and there are other conditions on top of that for preemption. If congress passes such a law without a workable legal theory, it won't survive a challenge in court.

Comment: @phoog No. I'm actually interested more generally in how the fed can nullify state laws (when I asked that people didn't like it so I'm giving a specific example of what that would be). I could only assume they use the commerce clause like when they add further restrictions. But something about the idea of a law addresing state laws instead of businesses or individuals seems strange to me.

Answer (score 4):

**Short Answer**

Could Congress nullify a state's minimum wage law and force it to be lowered?

Congress could effectively nullify a state's minimum wage law by passing a federal law that applied in all U.S. states that expressly authorized private sector employers to pay private sector employees less than a state or local government's minimum wage down to a federal minimum wage. This would override a conflicting state or local minimum wage laws.  When a federal law nullifies a state law we say that the state law is "[pre-empted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_preemption)" by federal law.

But Congress could not force a state or local government to change its minimum wage law, even though contrary laws that would remain on the statute or ordinance books of state or local government in question would be invalid and unenforceable.

Congress likewise could probably not force a state government to pay its employees a lower amount that the minimum wage established by state law.

The somewhat involved constitutional law legal analysis that gets you to this result is set forth below.

**Long Answer**

There is no case directly on point, because Congress has never actually tried to cap a state's minimum wage. But, existing case law nonetheless provides fairly clear guidance about how this question would be resolved if it presented itself.

There are some aspects of the constitutional law establishing the scope of the authority of Congress to enact legislation under the Interstate Commerce Clause, and regarding the federalism balance between the federal government on one hand and state and local government on the other, which are in flux and hard to predict right now as a more conservative U.S. Supreme Court rolls back decades of well established U.S. Supreme Court precedents. But this particular question doesn't present any of the legal issues in these areas of constitutional law that hotly contested at this point (assuming that the Congressionally enacted law at issue was sufficiently clearly drafted).

The boundaries of the federal government's authority to regulate economic matters on a national basis wasn't tested very much in the first century or so of the U.S. Constitution adopted in 1789, because, in practice, Congress didn't try to do so, and the federal government was tiny prior to the U.S. Civil War (1861-1865). But as the United States industrialized and the scale of the federal government grew during and after the U.S. Civil War, Congress, in what is known as the "progressive era" at the end of the 19th century and the early 20th century, started to attempt to regulate private economic activity on a national basis much more vigorously.

In the [*Lochner* era](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lochner_era) (1897-1937), named after the case of *Lochner v. New York*, [198 U.S. 45](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/198/45/) (1908), the U.S. Supreme Court greatly limited the authority of Congress to directly regulate matters like employer-employee relations within a given state on the substantive due process grounds that an implied freedom of contract in the 14th Amendment rendered such laws unconstitutional at the federal level.

But, a threat by FDR and his democratic supermajorities in Congress during the Great Depression broke this judicial barrier to national regulation of economic activity by threatening to pack the court with liberals who would reverse the *Lochner* era doctrines that had prevented it from doing so. The U.S. Supreme Court then disavowed the existing of a substantive due process right of freedom of contract, as well as some other legal doctrines that had been used to limit the power of Congress to engage in national economic regulation.

This culminated in the extreme case of *Wickard v. Filburn*, [317 U.S. 111](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/317/111/) (1942), in which the U.S. Supreme Court held that the Interstate Commerce Clause of Article I, Section 8 of the United States Constitution authorized Congress to regulate even the growing of grain for personal consumption on a farm that was entirely within one state, because this had an indirect effect on the national interstate market for grain in the United States, despite the fact that it involved no interstate transactions and no economic exchange of good or services between people that more restrictive definitions would call "commerce".

This was reinforced in the Civil Rights era in cases like *Heart of Atlanta Motel v. United States*, [379 US 241](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1964/515) (1964), in which the U.S. Supreme Court held that Congress, in passing Title II of the 1964 Civil Rights Act, did not exceed its Interstate Commerce Clause powers by depriving places of public accommodation, such as a motel with operations in a single state, of the right to choose their own customers by forbidding it from discriminating on the basis of race in cases involving no state action.

Thus, the power of Congress to enact laws related to economic matters pursuant to the Interstate Commerce Clause is almost unlimited.

There have been a handful of cases that have established that the Interstate Commerce Clause is not entirely limitless in scope, generally involving a conflict with another constitutional right or a regulation that is predominantly non-economic in character. But those have no application to the regulation of the wages and hours of private employees of private employers doing business only a single state, which have been routinely upheld since the *Lochner* era ended.

The U.S. Supreme Court has limited the authority of Congress to directly regulate the operations of state governments. This is called the [anti-commandeering doctrine](https://anti-commandeering%20doctrine), and is articulated in U.S. Supreme Court cases like *New York v. United States*, [505 U.S. 144](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/usrep/usrep505/usrep505144/usrep505144.pdf) (1992), which held that the Low-Level Radioactive Waste Policy Amendments Act of 1985, which, among other things, imposed upon states the obligation to provide for the disposal of waste generated within their borders, unconstitutionally commandeered states to enact legislation that the federal government directed it to enact.

So, Congress probably could not compel a state to actually reduce its statutory minimum wage. Similarly, Congress could not force a state government to pay its state government employees a lower amount (a mandate that would be further complicated by the fact that the state is the employer in that context and not just a regulator of private conduct).

But, Congress could expressly authorize private employers to pay their private sector employees less than the minimum wage set by state and local governments, for example, $2 per hour. And, if Congress did so, this law, pursuant to the Supremacy Clause of the U.S. Constitution (found in [Article IV, Clause 2 of the United State Constitution](https://constitution.congress.gov/browse/essay/artVI-C2-1/ALDE_00013395/)), would override and invalidate any contrary state laws or local ordinances that required private employers to pay their private sector employees a minimum wage greater than $2 per hour, because the federal law would actually conflict with the state law in that situation.

It isn't entirely clear if Congress could pass a law that, for example, set a federal minimum wage that expressly authorized private sector employees to pay less than the state minimum wage of $3 in New York State, but $7 in Utah. Except in the area of bankruptcy law (which, ironically, actually treats bankrupts in different states quite differently), Congress is not required to make federal laws uniform in all U.S. states and routinely does adjust the law between them (e.g. providing different health insurance tax breaks in different U.S. states based upon the cost of health insurance in that state and the poverty line in that state under the Affordable Care Act, also known as "Obamacare"). But usually, when Congress does so, there is some overarching guiding principle that applies to all states and it is not done purely arbitrarily.

I could image the current conservative U.S. Supreme Court striking down a non-uniform federal minimum wage law that overrode state and local minimum wage laws that rather than having some guiding principle for the different treatment of different states simply arbitrarily set different minimum wages in different states, although it is hardly certain or clear that the federal courts would do so.

Of course, this isn't what Congress has actually done. Instead, Congress has historically set a fairly low national minimum wage, which is far below what is necessary to live above the poverty line in places with a high cost of living, and state and local governments in places with a high cost of living have enacted their own additional minimum wage laws setting higher minimum wages in their jurisdiction.

Thus, a federal law which expressly authorized employers to pay less than a state or local minimum wage, which would be constitutional, but has never been attempted.

But, in the *status quo*, a state law that sets a minimum wage higher than the federal minimum wage, or a local law that sets a minimum wage higher than the federal or the state minimum wage, is valid and constitutional, because it doesn't not conflict with federal law. This is because, an employer who pays a high enough wage to that employer's employees can satisfy the federal minimum wage law, the state minimum wage law, and the local minimum wage law at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. It is counterintuitive, however, that a government could pass a law *allowing* someone to do something, instead of restricting the ability to do something. It would be more intuitive to e.g. restrict the formation of contracts that disallow things but I am only aware of laws applying such restrictions to private actors, outside of the Constitution. (Indeed the fed would be adding amendments to state constitutions in effect.) Are you aware of actual examples of such laws?

Comment: @user84614 Plenty of laws allow people to do things. There are laws allowing police and soldiers to use force in ways that ordinary citizens cannot. There is the "dormant commerce clause" and the constitutional right to travel. There are the 1st Amendment which allow people to do things. Europe has "right to roam" statutes. There are laws allowing people to commit assisted suicide. Sometimes laws that allow people to do things are called laws establishing "liberties" or "rights."